# How to append to { asset ('/') }, prefix URL build gulp-useref task on my an includable page

Tags: laravel-5, gulp, laravel-blade, gulp-useref

I used gulp and Laravel blade when run gulp,

*Do I want thing?*

I want {{ asset('/') }} append to perfix URL build

---

*head-include.blade.php* **Before** running gulp

```
<!-- build:css  resources/assets/css/out.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/assets/css/1.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/assets/css/2.css">
<!-- endbuild -->
```

gulpfiles.js

```
...
gulp.task('useref', function(){
  return gulp.src(paths.assets.html)
  .pipe(useref())
  .pipe(gulpIf('*.js', uglify()))

  .pipe(gulpIf('*.css', cssnano()))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dev.html))
});
...
```

*head-include.blade.php* **After** running gulp

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/assets/css/out.css">
```

---

> **But i want it:**
>
> i want {{ asset('/') }} append to perfix url build

head-include.blade.php **I want ..**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('/') }} resources/assets/css/out.css">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

install gulp-replace

> npm install gulp-replace --save-dev

```
replace = require('gulp-replace');

gulp.task('useref', function(){
  return gulp.src(paths.assets.view)
    .pipe(replace("{{ asset('resources/assets') }}", 'resources/assets'))
    .pipe(useref())
    // Minifies only if it's a JavaScript file
    .pipe(gulpIf('*.js', uglify()))
    // Minifies only if it's a CSS file
    .pipe(gulpIf('*.css', cssnano()))

    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dev.view))

    .pipe(replace('../assets', "{{ asset('resources/assets') }}"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dev.view))
});
```

---

```
<!-- build:css(./)  resources/assets/css/out.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('resources/assets') }}/css/1.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('resources/assets') }}/css/2.css">
<!-- endbuild -->
```